# generics type declaration for reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938526/java-generics-bounds-type) about differences between

```
public static <T> void work(Class<T> type, T instance);
```

and

```
public static <T, S extends T> void work(Class<T> type, S instance);
```

I think I should explain what exactly I want to know. Updating the original question is not proper for this time, I think, so I'm asking an another question here.

Say, I want to make a single reflected method for invoking those `marshal` methods defined in [Marshaller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) such as

```java
void marshal(Object element, ContentHandler handler)
void marshal(Object element, File output)
void marshal(Object element, Node node)
```

and so on.

One of method that I'm working on is

```java
void marshal(Object jaxbElement, Class<?> targetType, Object target)
```

The implementation is simple

1. Find a method looks like `marshal(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)V` with `Object.class` and `targetType`
2. invoke the method with `element` and `target`.

So any unit testing code can invoke like

```java
marshal(element, ContentHandler.class, handler);
marshal(element, File.class, new File("text.xml"));
```

In this case how should I define the `marshal` method? Is there any difference between

```java
<T> marshal(Object element, Class<T> targetType, T target);
```

and

```java
<T, S extends T> marshal(Object element, Class<T> targetType, S target)
```

?

**Further Comments per Answers**

I think I need the `targetType` for fast and direct method looking the right method.

Without the `targetType` I have to iterate all methods like

```
for (Method method : Marshaller.class.getMethods()) {

    // check modifiers, name, return type, and so on.

    if (!method.getParameterTypes()[1].isAssignableFrom(target.getClass())) {
    }
}
```

Adding another version for this will be better, I think. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know why you want the class object, because if you have an instance of `T` you can do this in the method:

```
Class<T> targetType = target.getClass(); // class may be derived from the instance
```

However, if you really need to pass a class, I think you want this:

```
<T> void marshal(Object element, Class<? super T> targetType, T target) {

}
```

By using `Class<? super T>` you achieve the flexibility of passing a Class that is a super class of the instance without the extra generic method parameter.

Comment: Because with just `target.getClass()` I think I have to check all those `marshal` methods' second parameter for comparability, right?

Comment: Wow, `<? super T>` is something big! I should read `Effective Java` again. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't do `<? super T>` since that feels like the opposite of what is intended. It IMO encourages to call `marshal(element, Object.class, someFile)` instead of `.., File.class, potentiallySomeSubTypeOfFile)`. Also [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2723538/995891): while not perfectly applicable it's easy to see that `targetType` is no consumer of things that are of type T. The restriction that is intended for `targetType` is that it is exactly one of `File`, `ContentHandler`, ... - but that restriction can't be encoded into the method signature so I would not try to put it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the class at T, you don't need to feed it in the arguments, so `<T, S extends T> marshal(Object element, S target)` should be enough. But since `S extends T`, `S` can be recognized as `T`.

Unless you specifically need methods that are only in class `S`, you can omit it and write

```
<T> marshal(Object element, T target)
```

However, since you are creating a generic method, you probably won't need to declare S. This for the following reason:

- if the methods of S differ from T, there is no good way to determine the methods of several different classes of S. Unless they have a common interface, but then you might as well use the common interface as `T`.
- if the methods of S do not differ, there is not reason to specifically indicate it as generic operand.

Comment: But you have no idea what methods are in `S`! You could not possibly need in for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in what sets of arguments that

`<T> marshal(Object element, Class<T> targetType, T target);`

and

`<T, S extends T> marshal(Object element, Class<T> targetType, S target)`

can accept.

Therefore, if you are writing an API, you should prefer the simpler one, the one with fewer type parameters, i.e. the one without `S`.